# Run processing tools in Python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console

I have created two scripts for my QGIS project. I need to do a manual step after the first script for the second script to work. The second step involves a QGIS tool called "join by nearest". I would like to build this step into my script, but I have trouble running the tool from the Python console. It runs but does not give me an output layer. I am not sure if it doesn't do the job or just cannot provide the layer in the end.

I also want to accecss the vector layer from the current project and not put in the path of the file. I am not sure if I have done this correctly.

```py
from qgis.core import *
import processing

# Replace 'input_layer_name' with the actual name of your vector layer in the QGIS project
input_layer_name = "layer name in project"
input_layer_name_2  = 'Abschnitte LAP Stufe 4'
output = "C:/Users/QGis LAP/Skripte/output.shp"

processing.run("native:joinbynearest", {
    'INPUT': input_layer_name,
    'INPUT_2': input_layer_name_2,
    'FIELDS_TO_COPY': ['fid'],
    'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
    'PREFIX': '',
    'NEIGHBORS': 1,
    'MAX_DISTANCE': None,
    'OUTPUT': 'output'
})
output_layer = result['OUTPUT']

# Add the output layer to the map canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the params you have the output `'output'`, which is just a string. But you need to use the variable `output`

Then replace `processing.run(algo, params)` with the following:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults(algo, params)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!